# How do I paginate combined results in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, pagination

I have a `User` model, and two different associated models `Profile`, `WorkProfile`. The `profile` model contains general info about the user line name, email, home address e.t.c, `workprofile` contains details like current office address, office phone, office email e.t.c. The user model stores the `objectID` of these two and refers to them with `profile` and `workprofile` keys.

Now what I am trying to build is an advanced search on user model based on the fields in these associated models. One way I see is to query them separately and then use `_.concat` to join the results. But the problem with that is I can't implement `skip` or `limit` on the final result to get proper pagination. What would be the best way to do this with proper pagination?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ref` on profile and workprofile You can add it to user like bellow, this allows for using find method with `profile.name`, etc.

```
var ProfileSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

var WorkProfileSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: String
});

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    profile: ProfileSchema,
    work_profile: WorkProfileSchema 
});    

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

var user = new User({
    profile: {name: 'Molda'},
    work_profile: { email: 'my@email.com'}
});

user.save(function(err, u) {

    User.findOne({'profile.name':'Molda'},function(err, user) {

        console.log('user', user);

    })

});
```

or even use simple objects

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    profile: {
        name: String
    },
    work_profile: {
        email: String
    }
});
```

This might not be always good idea but it's possible.